# Merge search multiple condition - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to understand the merge search condition and have come across the following problem.

Table1

```
id  groupid    description
-------------------------    
1     10       Good
2     20       Better
```

Table2

```
id  groupid   description
-------------------------    
1    10       Very Good
1    20       Much Better
```

I intend to merge the source (table1) to target (table2) on the id present in both but only groupid = 20 present in target table.

Here is what I am writing

```
Merge table1 source
Using table2 target ON (target.id = source.id AND target.groupid = 20)

When Matched
    Then update 
             set target.description = source.description
```

The output I am expecting is

Table2

```
id  groupid   description
-------------------------   
1     10      Very Good
1     20      Good
```

But I am not 100% sure of the ON clause (merge search condition) with multiple conditions of checking `target.id = source.id and target.groupid = 20`. Is the result always predictable and matching the expectation above in these multiple conditions ? Or is predictability a  question here and should I be adding `target.groupId = 20` in the "when matched AND" condition ?

Comment: Well you said table 2 was the target but then used it as the source in your query. On looks fine to me otherwise... which is another way of writing the WHERE clause.

Comment: table2, row 2 : isn't id=1 a mispint?

Comment: @scsimon- Thanks for pointing the typo, edited the same.

Comment: @Serg-No its not a misprint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your join is wrong. You are either needing to join on the GROUPID or your data is incorrect.

**JOINING ON GROUP**

```
create table #table1 (id int, groupid int, description varchar(64))
create table #table2 (id int, groupid int, description varchar(64))

insert into #table1 values
(1,10,'Good'),
(2,20,'Better')


insert into #table2 values
(1,10,'Very Good'),
(1,20,'Much Better')


Merge #table2 t
Using #table1 s 
ON (t.groupid = s.groupid AND t.groupid = 20)
When Matched
Then update 
set t.description = s.description;

select * from #table2

drop table #table2
drop table #table1
```

Otherwise, there isn't any way to correlate "better" from `ID = 2` to a row where `ID = 1`. This goes against your original join condition on the `ID` column.

**BASED OFF EDITED EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
create table #table1 (id int, groupid int, description varchar(64))
create table #table2 (id int, groupid int, description varchar(64))

insert into #table1 values
(1,10,'Good'),
(2,20,'Better')


insert into #table2 values
(1,10,'Very Good'),
(1,20,'Much Better')


Merge #table2 t
Using #table1 s 
ON (t.id = s.id)         --you could also put the and t.groupid = 20 here...
When Matched and t.groupid = 20
Then update 
set t.description = s.description;

select * from #table2

drop table #table2
drop table #table1
```

Comment: @scsimon-can you please relook into the output, i have edited the question.

Comment: @scsimon- interestingly in the edited output you have put t.groupid=20 in when matched condition. I saw your comment that it can be added in on condition as well. Is there a specific reason related to performance that you added t.groupid = 20 in when matched or is it conventionally correct ?

Comment: @100pipers  either is fine except when I place it on the when matched part this means it would only be applied to this section of merge. If after this part we had a WHEN NOT MATCHED then the groupid = 20 wouldn't apply unless we included it again. Placing it in the join would mean bother matched and unmatched would apply the groupid = 20 limit